# reuse logic in suspendable and nonsuspendable functions

Tags: kotlin

The following two method contain the same functionality, the only difference is that one is suspendable and the other isn't (same for parameters).

How can I extract the implementation and reuse it for both functions?

```
fun validationWrapper(supplier: () -> Unit) = try {
    supplier.invoke()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    when (ex) {
        is IllegalArgumentException, is IllegalStateException -> throw ValidationException(ex.message!!)
        else -> throw ex
    }
}

suspend fun validationWrapper(supplier: suspend () -> Unit) = try {
    supplier.invoke()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    when (ex) {
        is IllegalArgumentException, is IllegalStateException -> throw ValidationException(ex.message!!)
        else -> throw ex
    }
}
```

I could keep only the suspendable function but that would mean I should use a `runBlocking` each time I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the non-suspend version and make it `inline`. This solves the problem because the inlined lambda can then contain suspending calls without being declared `suspend` itself. It is how most of the Kotlin stdlib does this (`forEach`, `map`, etc.):

```kotlin
inline fun validationWrapper(supplier: () -> Unit) = try {
    supplier.invoke()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    when (ex) {
        is IllegalArgumentException, is IllegalStateException -> throw ValidationException(ex.message!!)
        else -> throw ex
    }
}
```

Also, it is generally useful for higher-order functions that take lambdas to be declared `inline`, because it avoids extra costs of lambda instances.